# Set jQuery Toggle to be open on ASP.Net Gridview Postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a jQuery *'toggle'* function on a table that I am using in conjunction with an asp.net gridview. I have pagination on my gridview and when I click on the next page, it posts back and therefore closes the Toggle/Table - I need a way of keeping it open. I have had a similar issue in the past with the Accordion function **but resolved it via this method and wondered if one of you jQuery/Javascript geniuses could help:**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidAccordionIndex" runat="server" Value="0" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var activeIndex = parseInt($('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val());

            $("#accordion").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                event: "mousedown",
                active: activeIndex,
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    var index = $(this).children('h3').index(ui.newHeader);
                    $('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val(index);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href="#">Table Header 1 here</a></h3>
        <div>
            Some text here
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Table Header 2 here</a></h3>
        <div>
```

Here is my current code that I have the issue with:

```
<div class="box grid_16 round_all">
                    <h2 class="box_head grad_colour round_top">Client List</h2> 
                    <a href="#" class="toggle toggle_closed">&nbsp;</a>
                    <div class="toggle_container" style="display:none;">
                        <asp:Label ID="LBLMessage" runat="server" />
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvClients" runat="server" CssClass="static" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="true" Visible="true" />
                    </div>
            </div>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
// Content Box Toggle Config 
        $("a.toggle").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("toggle_closed").next().slideToggle("slow");
            return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
            $("a.toggle").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("toggle_closed").next().slideToggle("slow", function () {
                    if($(this).is(':visible')){
                    $('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val("1");
                    }
                    else{
                    $('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val("0");
                    }
                });
                return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
            });
            var val = $('#<%=hidAccordionIndex.ClientID %>').val();
            if (val == "1") {
                $("a.toggle").click();
            }
        });

<asp:HiddenField ID="hidAccordionIndex" runat="server" Value="0" />
```

**Update 1:**
Check this [test page](http://aspspider.ws/dotnetguys/togglegv.aspx). GV paging isn't functional but it does simulate the scenario. Let me know in terms of this example how it differs from what you are expecting.
Wondering if you want to use UpdatePanel and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you explain in what way it is not working? Do you have a link where I can see that in action?

Comment: when I click on the next page of results, the toggle closes again as a post back has been sent. Unfortuantely I cannot show you it as its only running on my local machine and I have no way of putting it on a live server at the moment - i have pasted the RAW HTML that is output here if that helps - http://pastebin.com/EbuTPpPx

Comment: Check the test page I have set up.